# Drag and drop folders into other folders (like a file system) with React - React Drag and Drop?

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, drag-and-drop, filesystems, react-dnd

I'll soon be tasked with implementing some drag and drop UI that allows for the creation of folders, and then the nesting of folders within folders, and then the nesting of folders within folders...and so on.  You get it - basically a filesystem.

My first thought was to go with React DND.  But it doesn't seem like react DND offers [nesting of items within items of like kind](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/examples/nesting/drag-sources).

[Stack overflow searches](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=drag%20and%20drop%20folders%20react) are a not yielding much to other folks on the same path.

Am I missing the obvious places that I might find a compendium of resources available to help people make filesystems?

The [react component tree](https://github.com/react-component/tree) library is the only thing I've found that seems to allow folders within folders.

While I realize that deeply nesting (beyond 3 or 4 levels) is not a feature that I might want to offer the user, I'm surprised that most off-the-shelf solutions only go one or maybe two levels deep, and don't allow nesting of items within items of like kind.

Looking to clarify the path to finding libraries for those who come after me!

Comment: Did you actually found a solution? Because I want to build the same thing